# Cloning Windows installation (while in use) to new drive, without leaving Windows

Tags: windows, hard-drive, clone

Is it possible to just copy and paste, or do I actually need to clone it at a lower level?

I've tried DriveImage XML, but it complains about the fact the source drive is in use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What OS? Windows 7's built-in image backup will make a full system image while your computer is running, which you can then restore to a new hard disk by booting off of the installation disk and choosing "repair", then choosing to restore from an image.

Answer (score 1):

I used [Acronis](http://www.acronis.com/) and it worked perfectly.

Comment: I have tried this, but my source drive (C:\\) is greyed out.

Comment: Not sure what is wrong, I have used Acronis to clone drives in use for years.

Comment: I use Casper to do this all the time. http://www.fssdev.com/products/casper/

I was under the impression Acronis should work fine though...I dunno.  Is the C: drive larger than all the other drives maybe?