# Create bootable clone Windows 7 while running 

Tags: windows-7, backup, encryption, clone

I'm issued a SafeBoot encrypted computer at work, and I'd like to decrypt, clone, and then reinstall with something cross-platform like TrueCrypt. In order to have a clone that's useful at all, I need to backup while I'm logged in to Windows 7, otherwise I'll just be cloning encrypted data. My end goal is to have a dual boot system, but this is impossible with SafeBoot.

I do this regularly with Carbon Copy Cloner on my home Mac and it works fine. Surely there's something that makes a bootable backup for Windows 7?

Is what I'm trying to do feasible?

Spare any comments re. this not being a good idea. I'm aware of the risks, if any. I've conversed about my doings with a higher-up in IT who I know well, I've discussed my Linux use with the IT center, etc. They know, they don't care, but they're not going to help and I'm not going to ask my manager to sign stuff to authorize an actual decryption of my whole system (removal of SafeBoot) just for this.

I just want to see if it's feasible. If it's not, I'll just use VirtualBox or something.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: If this is a work computer, you _really_ ought to talk to your IT staff about this. Chances are they won't want you changing the encryption scheme on your laptop. There are probably policies in place for liability which depend on you having their specific encryption software installed, and whether you like that or not, you should not go about trying to circumvent that yourself.

Comment: If you want to back up windows while booted into windows, see this question about [cloning windows while it's in use](http://superuser.com/questions/178249/cloning-windows-installation-while-in-use-to-new-drive-without-leaving-windows). I don't know how you'll get the image back onto the newly re-encrypted disk though.

Comment: +1 for @nhinkle's comment. Companies have a specific data protection requirement (at least in US and UK) and if you breach it you could end up in a very bad legal/disciplinary position! Typically removing your safeboot protection is likely to breach their requirements.

Comment: @nhinkle/Rory Alsop: thanks for the suggestion. What surprises me is that I have, indeed, talked about this with my last laptop with my building IT guy. And not just anyone -- this guy is definitely higher up the ladder. At first I was running from a USB drive as to not change anything, but post-installing Linux over *the whole thing*, all he suggested to me was installing ClamAV for virus protection. I could go find some VP and get a blood-signed paper saying what I want to do is okay... but then again, there have been a reasonable amount of opportunities for stopping me; none have occurred.

Comment: @nhinkle: I'd prefer not to buy Acronis, and the Win7 built-in tools sound like they require one to boot from a disk and restore; one can not boot from the backup itself. Is that accurate? If so, I can fiddle with the Win7 stuff a bit more and test it on another computer to make sure it's working right.

Comment: You might look at Storage Craft product, http://www.storagecraft.com/documents/4-0-tour/sp40.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the questions. I stumbled on my own solution that I think is somewhat unique. It has the benefit of taking heed to the cautions above (not fiddling with company stuff -- at least not much), leaves everything encrypted, dual boots, and lets both OSs access shared data. In short, the solution was like so:

- Defrag
- Use Windows 7 partition table to shrink itself as small as possible (ended up being about 130G for me)
- Create three more partitions form the resultant unallocated space:

  - 64M for Linux /boot
  - 30G for Linux
  - The rest for TrueCrypt
- Use [MiniTool Partition Wizard Home Edition](http://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html) to set the partition types that will be Linux based as having IDs of 0x83 (from their created ID of 0x7 for NTFS)
- Use [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1) to create a Linux boot entry in the Windows boot options menu
- Install Linux with [LUKS/dm-crypt encryption](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/System_Encryption_with_LUKS)
- Install grub to the /boot partition, not the MBR
- Create a TrueCrypt encrypted device from the last partition from either Win or Linux for shared storage

So... perhaps I've still "violated" the IT policy via the letter of the law -- I'm not positive, but don't really think this is the case based on talking about my plans with someone reasonably high in IT.

I've thought more about it, though, and called to mind that my company has no issues with people using their personal MacBooks at work, and I know on IT guy who uses one and uses TrueCrypt (or maybe it was FireVault) to encrypt his work files on it. Many probably don't encrypt at all, I would suspect.

So, if the issue is purely that this is "company property" vs. my personal computer, I may be an offender. If the issue is due diligence to protect everything, I've say I've covered the bases. Even more so, I've exceeded what I hoped for above -- the SafeBoot partition and default MBR are all still exactly as they were, safe being shrunk and a slightly modified partition table. I've verified that company patches still work, and thus I should be "on the grid" to the fullest with this setup.

I think all in all it was quite successful.

I wrote up the procedure [HERE](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dual_boot_with_Windows_when_SafeBoot_is_installed#Create_a_Shared_TrueCrypt_Volume), as I hadn't seen anyone use this particular method in my searching. Thanks for all the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Haven't used it myself but googling for Carbon Copy Cloner equivalent came up with a couple of options. Acronis TrueImage - I have used it but to be honest I had a few issues. I'm not sure if they're the program's fault, I tried to restore my backup to somewhat different hardware and ran into problems. I've also seen TotalRecovery (formerly DriveClone) recommended. Good luck.